# Callback for onload image

Tags: javascript, callback, coffeescript

I'm trying to display the height & width of a  certain image inside a div. However its now displaying 'undefined'. I guess this has to do with that onload is an ASYN function. I'm pretty new to coffeescript/javascript and i'm trying to learn it. But how can I enable the callback?

```
getMeta = (url, callback) ->
  img = new Image()
  img.src = url
  console.log(img)
  img.onload = ->
    console.log("load")
    width = @width
    height = @height

imageUrl = "http://imgcdn.igdb.com/images/limbo/6843_screenshot_show_6843_at_igdb_com.jpg"
meta = getMeta imageUrl


$("#debug").html("Height: " + meta.height + "px W: " + meta.width + "px")
```

Answer (score 0):

But, if you really want it at the top, try:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#click").click(function() {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            $("#debug").html("Height: " + this.height + "px W: " + this.width + "px")
        }
        img.src = $("#img_url").val();
    });
});
```

and the HTML

```
<input id="img_url" type="text">
<div id="click">Click Here</div>

<div id="debug"></div>
```

Example: http://jdl-enterprises.co.uk/sof/25742662.php

Comment: I will need to call the function multiple times, as you did there the url is static + the div #debug also needs to be dynamic

Comment: Are you going to have an input box which calls it?